# Slow Performance VS2015 with Telerik

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, telerik

I haven't used Telerik controls before for desktop application. I'm wondering why my application is slow. My system spec is very good. For example if I select one control to add property and then I go for next control it takes some seconds to get selected. Even when I save, it takes some seconds to save. I have to wait every time I do something and save. My computer is in network. And I guess my computer is in different location not where I work. Is that the reason for slow performance even though the system spec is good enough?

Thank You!

Comment: Are you talking about Visual Studio being slow? If so, that's very common with XAML files. I find it can takes ages to save them, even when saving locally to an SSD. If you're saving across a network, it can be even slower. I use Telerik controls the whole time and have never found them to slow things down

Comment: Yes Visual studio. My PC spec is good. I don't even use XAML, I'm working with windows forms or RadForm from Telerik. It maybe because of network traffic. Let's see we gonna test that soon.

Comment: add more details about your PC and what is slow in detail. Does VS have a high CPU usage during the slowness